# Why is the letter spacing so much wider in old IE versions compared to newer browsers?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

I am cross browser testing my development site and after seeing some IE8 screen shots from a friend I was annoyed to see so many of my titles and paragraphs spilling onto new lines, when they all look so similar in FF, IE9 and Chrome.

Specifically IE8, the letter spacing seems so wide compared to these newer browsers. Is there something I can do to get them all in line with each other?

This is a good demo to see it: http://dev.enterf1.com/british-grand-prix/tickets.php

The H2's are set to -1px and look great in new browsers. If I set it to -2px it looks much better in IE8, but too squashed in newer browsers.

Anything I can do?

Answer (score 0):

Browsers have their own style sheets. You can use a CSS normalizer or resetter to level the playing field so all browsers render your style how *you* intend. IE8 obviously has a different base style than the others that suit your needs.

Check out http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/

If nothing else, you can use a conditional comment to set a class on the body for ie8, and then use the CSS rule specifically for that class. Consider the following:

```
<!--[if IE 9]><body class="ie9 ie"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><body class="ie8 ie"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]><body class="ie7 ie"><![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 6]><body class="ie6 ie"><![endif]-->
<![if !IE]><body><![endif]>
```

Then consider the following CSS:

```
h2 {
    font-size : 14px;
}

.ie8 h2 {
    font-size : 12px;
}
```

That will give you the desired outcome for ie8 only.

Comment: I gave it a go but my letter spacing was still wider in IE8 unfortunately, it's such a bugger!

Answer (score 0):

Possibly it's using a different font. Maybe your Win7/IE9 system is using Segoe font for example, but a WinXP/IE8 won't have that font installed, to it'll revert to Ariel or Verdana instead.

That would very easily explain the difference -- those fonts may look similar, but there can be significant differences in the width of the text between them.

You could make tweaks to try to solve it, but bear in mind that users of other operating systems and platforms may also have different fonts installed, and may also see things differently. Don't forget to test it on tablets and other devices you want to support. They will almost certainly render things like this differently to your desktop browser.

All this means it's probably a bad idea to rely on the font size being exactly as you see it in your own browser. Better advice would be to either allow the elements room to fit the text with a slightly bigger font, or allow them to adjust their size as required. Either way, an adaptive layout is probably the way to go here, rather than trying to force things to be pixel perfect.